# Change prompt character for a custom table key field

Tags: acumatica

How can I change the prompt character for the key field for my custom table.  The only way I know how to change it is to change the segmented key, but since this is a custom table, there is none.  Do I have to create one and tie it to my new table? If so, how do I do that?  Is there a parameter in the IsKey?

Comment: What do you mean by prompt character ? Do you mean configuring the <New> token for your custom table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into InputMask and DisplayMask attribute property.

```
[PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaa")]
```

Example of use:
InputMask = ">LLLLL"
InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaa"
InputMask = ">CC.00.00.00"

Full documentation of this feature can be found here:
https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d0758787-4c73-423b-8566-11c83f3acde8